"Swap With" Snowflake - Replicate for Postgres?
I current have a process in which a materialized view refreshes on a schedule after new data is loaded into supporting tables. This process takes long, but allows us to be certain that the service that picks up the materialized views has no operational issues.
I have a theory that creating a table will be quicker, I want to use this approach ideally with no downtime and have it in fact be notably quicker than the materialized view. It will be in postgres, I had used a similar process in Snowflake called "Swap With" and it was nice, I could  blue-green release, rollback to previous deployment.
Postgres does not have a swap with nor do I hear anyone talk about this approach online for postgres - why is that? Here is how I would implement in postgres - are there any considerations I am missing or does the below look good?
CREATE [TEMP] TABLE temp_table (LIKE original_table INCLUDING ALL);
INSERT INTO temp_table SELECT * FROM ("sql that creates the materialized view that I am trying to replace with this proces";
ALTER TABLE original_table RENAME TO original_table_old;
ALTER TABLE temp_table RENAME TO original_table;
DROP TABLE original_table_old;


Why a TEMP table? That will be gone when the connection is closed.

doesn't have to be temp table, good point, but any other thoughts @FrankHeikens
